# How to disable "Which device did you plug in?" prompt?

Tags: windows-10, audio, dell-inspiron, headphone-jack

Recently I got Dell Inspiron laptop.  Every time I plug in my headphones it prompts me with this dialog `Which device did you plug in?`

[image]

Is there a way to disable this prompt?  I never get such prompt on other laptops.

**Other Info**

OS: Windows 10.
Sound driver:  Realtek Audio [ 6.0.1.7962 ]
MaxAudioPro

Comment: this is no windows dialog, this comes from a (audio) driver software

Comment: It's the Waves Maxx Audio software which generates the pop-up. You can disable it in the preferences or uninstall it (you'll still continue to get sound)

Answer (score 17):

To **Enable** or **Disable** In Windows 10 on a DELL

1. Open the program `WAVES MaxxAudio Pro`
2. Choose the device, eg. Playback
3. click `Advanced` in the bottom center of the window
4. Toggle the "Show pop-up dialog when device is connected" checkbox

[image: This is what I see (Windows 10 Pro V.1790 [XPS 8920])]

Comment: I have no "advanced" button. XPS 13 9360

Comment: I have the 'advanced' button, but the dialog does not have the mentioned toggle button.

Comment: I added a pic of what I see, for Windows 10 Pro, Dell XPS 8920

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `control panel` and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, select `Hardware and Sound`.
2. Scroll down and select `Realtek HD Audio Manager`.
3. Click the `folder icon` just above and to the right of where it says analog back panel and just below Device Advanced settings.
4. Uncheck `Enable auto popup dialog when device has been plugged in`.
5. Click `OK` twice.
6. Now, restart the computer and check the issue.

Comment: I dont see any `Hardware and sound` option in control panel.

Comment: Change the `View by` to `Category`

Comment: Please change the win+x, as control panel will no longer be available that menu when the creators update is relesed (i'm using `Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview`, `fast build`:`15031.rs2_release.170204-1546`

Comment: @DanHolli, I don't know why I should change it because of that. We are trying to help a real situation here, nothing to do with future updates.

Comment: @YisroelTech Now I can see `hardware and sound` but there is no `Realtek HD Audio Manager`  .  Inspiron comes with `MaxxAudioPro` could that be the reason?

Comment: @YisroelTech, To future proof your answer, I recommend the start-menu search method

Comment: @RakeshJuyal, in `Hardware and sound` what is the audio manager you do see? Do you have `Dell Audio` there?

Comment: #4 (Uncheck `Enable auto popup`) worked for me, though in `Realtek HD Audio Manager` it was in `Device Advanced settings` (cogwheel icon) -> `Options` -> Uncheck `Enable auto popup...`

Comment: This answer would be better with images. I've followed as much as I can and I don't see what you're describing. No `Realtek HD Audio Manager`, no `Dell Audio`, etc.

Comment: there is a disconnect between #1 and #2. "Hardware and Sound" do not bring up a list that allows selecting the desired device. "Control Panel/Hardware and Sound" is not the dialog referred to at #2. At least, it's not for me.

Comment: This option was within the "Realtek Audio Console" UWP application ("RtkUWP.exe" from the "RealtekSemiconductorCorp.RealtekAudioControl" package) for me, under "Device advanced settings" in the sidebar.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me with realtek audio console -- [Disabling Realtek audio notification on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1021033/disabling-realtek-audio-notification-on-windows-10)

**Go to Settings > System > Notifications and actions** and under **Get notifications from these senders**, scroll down and turn off `Realtek HD Audio Console`

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked for me on a ACER Spin 3 with Win10Edu.
(No WavesMAXX on my computer, and the Control Panel / Hardware and Sound  menu does not show any Realtek menu).

Comment: That stops the popups but also the audio switching, unless you disable jack detection in the Realtek Audio Console, which also stops the question on my MSI GL63 9SD.

Comment: This works for me on my Acer Predator. Also, I have WavesMaxx on my computer, but none of those answers did it for me; some or other problem.

Comment: not at all working

Comment: I can confirm that this works for Acer Predor Helios 300. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

- go to task manager & start-up tab,

  - found WavesMAXX Audio settings, and opened it's properties, to find its full path C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wavesapo.inf_amd_whatever is next..
  - opened executable thereMaxx AudioPro and tune-up the settings to pop-up the window on JACK insert.

Answer (score 1):

- Open task manager: right-click on the Windows taskbar > `Task Manager`.
- Go to the `Start-up` tab
- Disable the following (right-click > `Disable`):

  - `HD Audio Background Process`
  - `Realtek HD Audio Manager`
  - `Waves MaxxAudio Service Application`
- Restart your computer

This removed the prompt for me, and I've had no trouble with audio so far.

Not sure what else these do but you can always enable individually if you wish.

(N.B. In older versions of Windows, these start-up options may be in <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > `msconfig`.)

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving a prompt with the same text, but a different appearance.
I resolved it by searching the start menu for "Realtek Audio Console", then clicking "Device advanced settings" -> "Enable Jack detection when device is plugged in" -> Off

Comment: This link has an image of the dialog UI I was seeing:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/how-to-disable-which-device-did-you-plug-in/ae3f40a4-2d30-4d8a-b9b9-f2a1efa658e0 .  It has a "clock thing" in the upper left corner.  (The "clock thing" turns out to be the icon for Realtek Audio.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Alienware use Alienware audio advanced then jack info that is actually how I enabled mine works to disable too.

Answer (score 0):

They have removed that check box "show popup ..."  from the prompt in the latest version.
You cannot uninstall as well.
But I went to "services", disabled Waves Audio Service and rebooted. No more annoying pop-up when I plug in the headphones. Thank you all for your responses.

This is the hopeless feature that anybody can implement - what an horrible business usecase? who needs this functionality????

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Your post doesn't appear to address the question in a useful manner.  Specifically, given the various software versions discussed, you need to specify what system you are on and it would be more helpful to show screenshots of how you got to the "disable" step.  You will find that you will have a better experience if you take moment to take the Stack Overflow [tour].  If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Comment: Or, better yet, take [the ***Super User*** tour](/tour) and follow the norms of the ***Super User*** community.   :-)  ⁠

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I was trying to turn it back on after accidentally turning it off. My answer is a combination of [MST's](https://superuser.com/a/1396573/148107) and [Chad's](https://superuser.com/a/1267991/148107) answers on this page but with pictures since neither worked on their own.

- Open Task Manager and find "Waves MaxxAudio Service Application"

  [image: Task Manager]
- Right click it and select "Properties"

  [image: Right click Waves MaxxAudio Service Application]
- Find the location

  [image: Properties for Waves MaxxAudio Service Application]
- Go to the location in Windows Explorer

  [image: Windows Explorer]
- Run "MaxxAudioPro.exe"
- Select "Playback" (top left icon of two speakers)

  [image: MaxxAudioPro]
- Press "Advanced"

  [image: MaxxAudioPro Playback]
- Set "Show pop-up dialog when device is connected" to your preference

  [image: MaxxAudioPro Advanced]
- Plug your audio device in to test!

  [image: MaxxAudioPro Jack - 0]