# Can't swap between audio devices - Windows 11

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-11

So I accidentally clicked "Don't show this again" on the dialog box that lets me choose which audio device to use when I plug in my headphones. Now it just won't swap at all, unless I restart/boot up my laptop with the headphones plugged in.

Even then, if I unplug them, then connect them again, it won't detect them.

I have uninstalled the RealTek Audio device in the Device Manager, installed a different driver, reverted back again, disabled and enabled it again, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to question: [Always use laptop mic when headset is plugged in](https://superuser.com/questions/1363978/always-use-laptop-mic-when-headset-is-plugged-in/175956)

Specifically the part about enabling multi-streaming mode on the RealTek HD Audio advanced settings. This will allow you to control internal and external (audio jack) separately.