# Laptop microphone cannot be used with headphones plugged in on Asus VivoBook 15 X512DA

Tags: laptop, audio, windows-11, microphone, asus-laptop

My Asus VivoBook 15 X512DA cannot detect a difference between plugged in headphones and its regular unplugged speakers. This is normally not a problem—my previous headphones had a microphone built in, so I could use the microphone and headphones and it would connect automatically, despite not recognising any new audio devices.

(While it thinks it is playing through its own speakers and using its own microphone, somehow it knows i've plugged something in, because the audio levels change to what they were when I previously plugged them in, and Realtek Audio Console opens automatically. Yet, no new device can be seen in *Sounds*.)

I have done most stuff I see online. Reinstalled audio drivers, installed latest ones, tried the high def audio driver instead of Realtek, etc. Not sure what I can do short of a factory reset or reset to recovery point, the latter of which I have already tried and the former I won't do if its the only option, as (1) i'm not sure it'd even work, and (2) I wouldn't want to reset my laptop as some stuff in my storage is hard to back up.

Hopefully there is another way to fix? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See answer for: [Always use laptop mic when headset is plugged in](https://superuser.com/questions/1363978/always-use-laptop-mic-when-headset-is-plugged-in/175956)

specifically the multi-streaming advanced setting in the RealTek HD Audio settings. This will allow you to select internal and external speakers and microphones separately.