# How to get “Which device did you plug in?” prompt? (on Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, realtek-hd-audio

When I first got this laptop I used to get a pop up similar to the one discussed in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1177290/how-to-disable-which-device-did-you-plug-in-prompt).

[image: 4]

However, when I try to get MaxxAudio Pro from the Dell website I am told that it is not compatible with my computer.

[image: 3]

Currently I am at a loss as to what to do.

Comment: Do you need any help, or were you able to get it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I googled for `dell xps 13 9343 win 8` and found found the following article on the DELL support site:

This article provides information on identifying and installing drivers for Windows 8.1 on your XPS 13 9343 laptop.

[image]

After a clean installation of the Microsoft Windows 8.1 operating system, you must install the following drivers/software packages in the following sequence.

NOTE: Some components may not be present on your system depending on the original build and specification of the system. You may check your system's specific hardware configuration by following the steps listed in Dell Knowledge Base Article [sln128938: Checking Hardware Configuration (Driver Install)](https://www.dell.com/support/article/sln128938). Several of the drivers listed below may be automatically pre-installed during the Windows 8.1 installation. Be sure to check the Device Manager to ensure proper installation of each driver.
The list below indicates the recommended order to install the drivers for your system and provides links to additional information about each driver. Drivers are available for download on the [Dell Support Website](https://www.dell.com/support) for your system. Before choosing your drivers, ensure the correct Operating System version is selected from the drop down list (ie Windows 8.1 64 bit).

1. Chipset (System Devices) - [Intel Chipset and System Devices](https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl-nl/sln297325/identifying-and-installing-drivers-for-windows-8-1-on-your-xps-13-9343-laptop?lang=en#IntelChipsetandSystemDevices)
2. Display adapters - [Intel HD Graphics](https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl-nl/sln297325/identifying-and-installing-drivers-for-windows-8-1-on-your-xps-13-9343-laptop?lang=en#IntelHDGraphics)
3. Sound, video and game controllers - [Realtek Audio](https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl-nl/sln297325/identifying-and-installing-drivers-for-windows-8-1-on-your-xps-13-9343-laptop?lang=en#RealtekAudio)
4. IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers - [Intel Rapid Storage Technology](https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl-nl/sln297325/identifying-and-installing-drivers-for-windows-8-1-on-your-xps-13-9343-laptop?lang=en#IntelRapidStorageTechnology)
5. Network adapters - [Dell Wireless 1560 and Intel PROSet/Wireless Bluetooth](https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl-nl/sln297325/identifying-and-installing-drivers-for-windows-8-1-on-your-xps-13-9343-laptop?lang=en#DellWireless1560andIntelPROSetWirelessBluetooth)
6. Mouse, keyboard, and input devices - [Keyboard and Touchpad](https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl-nl/sln297325/identifying-and-installing-drivers-for-windows-8-1-on-your-xps-13-9343-laptop?lang=en#KeyboardandTouchpad)

Source: https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl-nl/sln297325/identifying-and-installing-drivers-for-windows-8-1-on-your-xps-13-9343-laptop?lang=en

So the correct driver should be this one: https://www.dell.com/support/home/nl-nl/drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=X22K2&fileId=3428752464&osCode=WB64A&productCode=xps-13-9343-laptop&languageCode=EN&categoryId=AU

Do note, because my system is dutch, Dell detected it and gave me a link for the dutch version of the website. If you use the links in the article to the english version of the site, you should be able to get the drivers in the correct language for your laptop.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way of getting my headset to work without doing a complete reinstall? Also my computer says that I have the correct version of the realtek audio driver.

Comment: I don't know. I don't have experience with this system on Windows 8.1. I just found the information you were looking for.

Comment: thanks for your help! I really appreciate it, but i will leave the question open for now just incase anyone has a solution that doesn't inovlve a complete reinstall

Comment: I don't think a clean install really is required. Its just how DELL stated that the drivers should be installed in that order. I bet that its only important to have the chipset drivers installed first, so if you uninstall the drivers completely, reboot then install the drivers linked here, it probably works.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I was trying to turn it back on after accidentally turning it off. My answer is a combination of [MST's](https://superuser.com/a/1396573/148107) and [Chad's](https://superuser.com/a/1267991/148107) answers on this page but with pictures since neither worked on their own.

- Open Task Manager and find "Waves MaxxAudio Service Application"

  [image: Task Manager]
- Right click it and select "Properties"

  [image: Right click Waves MaxxAudio Service Application]
- Find the location

  [image: Properties for Waves MaxxAudio Service Application]
- Go to the location in Windows Explorer

  [image: Windows Explorer]
- Run "MaxxAudioPro.exe"
- Select "Playback" (top left icon of two speakers)

  [image: MaxxAudioPro]
- Press "Advanced"

  [image: MaxxAudioPro Playback]
- Set "Show pop-up dialog when device is connected" to your preference

  [image: MaxxAudioPro Advanced]
- Plug your audio device in to test!

  [image: MaxxAudioPro Jack - 0]