# Corsair HS50 microphone attached to headset not working properly

Tags: audio, microphone, headset, headphone-jack, corsair

I just got a Corsair HS50 headset, which is a set of headphones with a detachable microphone. The microphone connects to the headphones via an ordinary 3-pin jack. There is only one wire coming out of the headset: a 4-pin connector. My PC is an Acer Aspire 3, and it's only got one jack. The jack on the PC is illustrated with a little icon of a headset (headphones with attached microphone), so presumably it's a 4-pin jack. However, when I plug the headset into this jack, the headphones work fine but the PC doesn't detect the attached microphone. It only detected the PC's built-in microphone, and used it on Skype.

So I got a Tecknet USB Audio Adapter, which plugs into a USB port on the PC and has separate red and green jacks for inputs. I plugged the 4-pin headset connector into a splitter cable and plugged the two 3-pin connectors at the other end of the splitter into the adapter.

Then the headphones continued to work fine and the PC detected the microphone. However, on Skype the microphone was so soft that I couldn't be heard. I checked the sound settings and it was set to 100% sensitivity, detected as a USB audio device.

I restarted my PC and went onto Discord. I checked to see that both my PC and Discord were using the USB audio device, and they said they were. But they *can't* have been, for at least two reasons. First, when I tapped on the microphone or blew into it, other people on Discord didn't hear anything. And second, most importantly, the headset has a mute button for the microphone, and whether it was clicked on or clicked off, the people on Discord heard me exactly the same. So they must have been hearing me through the PC's built-in microphone, despite the fact that both the PC and Discord claimed to be using the USB audio device for a microphone.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

EDIT 1: I have followed David Postill's advice in the comment below but it did not change the problem. I also plugged the headset straight into my PC's jack (without using the USB audio adapter) once I'd installed the iCUE software as per that advice, and the problem remained exactly the same.

EDIT 2: Once I installed new audio drivers on my PC, the headset started working. The problem was that it took several restarts for the microphone to start working, so I didn't realise I had a solution for a while.

Comment: [Fix Corsair headset sound issues after the Windows 10 build 1903 update or an iCUE software update – Corsair](https://help.corsair.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033489511-Fix-Corsair-headset-sound-issues-after-the-Windows-10-build-1903-update-or-an-iCUE-software-update)?

Comment: @DavidPostill I've now followed those instructions but the problem has not changed.

Comment: I would try contacting Corsair Tech Support ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I'll do that if the bounty I've put on the question fails to attract any answers, thanks.

Comment: 1-Do you have the latest audio driver? I'd find it for you, but you need a model number for Aspire 3 (ex: A315-57G). There appears to be an 'Audio Console' driver, I'd get that too. 2-Do you have a spare headset to try (some usually come with a smartphone)? 3-Sometimes there is an audio app for your sound card (Realtek, Acer, etc.) that you have to tell that you're plugging in a headset instead of speakers, did you do that? 
https://superuser.com/questions/1177290/how-to-disable-which-device-did-you-plug-in-prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do some more troubleshooting before you can determine what the issue is.  Try the following:

1. First, plug the new Corsair headset into a smartphone.  Every mainstream smartphone should be compatible with 4 pin jacks (actually not sure how apple tech works these days).  Call a friend, can they hear you?  can you hear them?  try muting the headset mic and determine whether the headset is working correctly.
2. Next, buy or loan a cheap pair of earphones that have a mic (and thus a 4 pin jack).  Plug them into your computer and do a test on discord or a program where you can monitor the inputs.  Do the earphones work correctly?  Does the mic work?
3. If in step one, the headset mic appears not to work in the phone, try the earphones in step 2 in the smartphone and ensure that they work.
4. Try removing the microphone from the headset and plugging it directly into the PC.  Test it with a program of your choice - does your PC receive input from the mic now? If so, there could be a connection issue in the headset.

The above steps should help you determine whether the PC is at fault, or if the headset is at fault.

If the earphones are working successfully in the PC, and the headset doesn't work in the phone then the headset may have a fault.  Check the manual: does it need additional power / batteries to function?  Does it need a particular software or driver installed?  Is there a setup issue?  If nothing appears to stand out, then contact the manufacturer for advice.

If the earphone mic is not working in the PC and the headset works in the phone, then it could be an issue with the audio input jack on the PC.  Use a bright light to examine the hole - is there any visible corrosion, water, or foreign objects?  Research your PC model to ensure that there isn't an audio driver required for the microphone to function.  Maybe the jack cannot simultaneously operate as an input and output?

This link has some helpful information on this issue: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/549334/how-can-i-fix-the-realtek-microphone-issue-in-windows-10-aspire-v3-772g -  see below (copy and pasted)

> Go to Control panel, Click Hardware and Sound. Under Sound click Manage Audio Devices. Click the Recording tab.
> Check if you can recognize which one of the devices in the list is your microphone. Click on the relevant device to highlight it, The list of recording devices will appear. Try speaking into your microphone, and look for green bars rising while you talk. Double-click on the device from the list. The Microphone Properties window will appear. Click the Levelstab. Drag the slider all the way to the right, until the number ’100′ is displayed beside it.

> If still microphone is not working, follow these steps to use the Troubleshooting tool:
> In Windows, search for and open Troubleshooting. Under Hardware and Sound, click Troubleshoot audio recording, then click Next when the Recording Audio window opens. Click Next in the Recording Audio window.
> Select the device you would like to troubleshoot, click Next, then follow the on-screen instructions.
> If a recommended action displays, select Apply this fix or Skip this step to continue to search for other problems.
> If issue persists try the below mentioned steps :
> Re-enable the microphone in privacy settings to allow apps to use the microphone, it is not muted.
> Disable Audio Enhancements , Recording devices > Enhancements tab > Disable all sound effects
> Reset Windows Audio service, Go to Search, type services.msc, and open Services.
> Find the Windows Audio service.If this service is not enabled, right-click it, and select Start. If it’s enabled, right-click it and select Restart.

> If the issue still persists, you can try reinstalling the audio driver Download
> Let us know if you need further assistance.

If the earphone mic doesn't work in the pc, but the headset doesn't work in the phone, then it could be a 2 part issue - both the PC and the headset need attention.

Comment: Thanks, @5Diraptor, once I installed new drivers and restarted my PC several times, the jack started working fine. It was kind of confusing because it didn't work after one restart.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted - windows can be a pig sometimes!  Would you be so kind as to mark my answer as correct when you get a chance?